# ImportFrom function in NAMESPACE is removed upon document()

Tags: r, import, namespaces, package, devtools

I am receiving an error [could not find function `"str_trim"`] when I run `check()` on an R package I am developing. I have since added two things:

```
1) In DESCRIPTION
Imports: stringr

2) In NAMESPACE
importFrom(stringr,str_trim)
```

However, when I then run `install()` and `document()`, then the line in NAMESPACE is removed. Then, when I again run `check()`, I receive the original error.

Why is this line being removed? Should I try a different approach, and if so, what kind of approach? Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

It seems you are doing package development "the Hadley way".
Hadley wants you to use roxygen (i.e. the roxygen2 package but that should be automatic if you use his 'devtools').
Then, the roxygen "magic" is used to auto-write your `NAMESPACE` file... and so also destroys things you've put there.
You must add `@importFrom` ....  statements to your R/*.R files if you want to use roxygen.

I agree with many things Hadley advocates;  the wholesale use of 'roxygen' is not among them however.
I want good, carefully maintained help files with \link{}s, \eqn{}, etc etc
-> I edit my `man/*.Rd` files and I manually build NAMESPACE (so it ends up looking well organized,  I can also add comments there, and I can even use
`if(getRVersion() >= "3.2.0")  {` ...... `}`  in the `NAMESPACE` file, something that's not easily possible with roxygen.